# iPhone: different icon for homescreen and App Store

Tags: iphone, icons, app-store

I would like to know if the app icon on the iPhone can be slightly different than the one shown in a large version in Apple's App Store.

It was discussed in short here: [Tips for a successful AppStore submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551/tips-for-a-successful-appstore-submission/266657#266657)

But I wanted to make sure if anyone has more experience with that.

To give an example: The New York Times has many words incorporated in its app icon (see http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/nytimes/id284862083?mt=8). Would it be okay to have a full black colored background without the words in the small/homescreen version of the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had one application (RefFinder) rejected just because the two didn't match. But they were quite different; I guess it's OK if they're only slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

yes i have submit couple of application with different app icon and big application icon on App store.

Here is one example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-business-credit-blueprint/id360499998?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

They can be different, but they have to accomplish the same design. I mean, they have to be recognized as the same applications (same colors, fonts.. same feeling)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the new `UIApplication.setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)` API in iOS 10.3 to change the app icon at runtime.

Note you need to ship the updated app icon as part of the app bundle however.