# How do I make a different icon name for the home screen and the App Store?

Tags: iphone

How do I make a different icon name for the home screen and the App Store in iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: different icon for homescreen and App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957215/iphone-different-icon-for-homescreen-and-app-store)

Comment: Hi Cody, Sorry, I could not come to conclusion based on the link. Could you please tell me if it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple requires that all of the icons, including the large 512x512 pixel icon for iTunes, be effectively identical. In my experience the large one can be more detailed (graphic textures, etc.), as long as anyone who saw both icons would be able to clearly tell they were for the same app.

The same rule is true for the name of the app in iTunes and the name that shows below the icon on the device: an average user should be able to easily tell that the names match in some way. I've had success with the name on the device being a shortened version of the full name, dropping things like articles ("the," "a," "an") and short prepositions ("for," "by," "on," etc.). I've also had to shorten the app name to its initials ("Fighting Chicks Unlimited" became "FCU"), and it passed without problem.

I have a couple of developer friends who have had their app rejected for the icons looking too dissimilar and for the name in the App Store and the one on the device being too different, so I know Apple definitely has a line you don't want to cross.

I advise that unless there's a very compelling reason for the icons or names to be drastically different, don't bother trying; rejection and resubmission can take weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess then that the answer your are looking for is that the icon shown in the app store is uploaded at the time you submit the app in iTunes Connect. It can then obviously be a different file but we recommend you to pass on a picture very close to what th app icon is otherwise your app could be rejected.