# Does iTunesConnect icon has to be the same as app icon from XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Does iTunesConnect icon has to be the same as app icon from XCode?
I am waiting about a week for app review, and now I want to change app icon. Could I do this only on itunesconnect?

Comment: I think that has to be the same as the icon used in Xcode(That is displayed on the screen when you install the app).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957215/iphone-different-icon-for-homescreen-and-app-store

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK if they are only slightly different. But they have to be recognised as the same app same colors, fonts and pattern.